# How can I do subplots in matplotlib with differents xlimit and size of axis-x?

Tags: python, matplotlib, size, subplot

How can I solve this? I want to do 4 subplots with matplotlib, I have used the subplot option but the result is just a big plot. I don't have idea what is the problem.  I want to see four subplots, each one with title, and a suptitle for them.

I don't have idea how can I solve it?

Can you help me please to fix it?
Thanks a lot

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
from pylab import text


with open("file1.txt") as f:
         m1 = map(float,f)

with open ("file2.txt") as f:
         m2 = map(float, f)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(sharey='row')
fig.set_figwidth(18)  #Width figure
fig.set_figheight(12) #Height figure

plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.18, hspace=0.2)

fig.suptitle('PLOTS', y=0.93, fontsize=15)

# Plot
plt.subplot(421)
y = np.array(m1)
x = np.arange(len(y))
threshold = 0.5
segments_x = np.r_[x[0], x[1:-1].repeat(2), x[-1]].reshape(-1, 2)
segments_y = np.r_[y[0], y[1:-1].repeat(2), y[-1]].reshape(-1, 2)
linecolors = ['red' if y_[0] > threshold and y_[1] > threshold else 'blue'
              for y_ in segments_y]
segments = [zip(x_, y_) for x_, y_ in zip(segments_x, segments_y)]
ax = plt.axes()
ax.add_collection(LineCollection(segments, colors=linecolors))
ax.set_ylim(-0.06, 1.07)
ax.set_xlim(0,268)
blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='ordenada')
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='desordenada')
plt.legend(handles=[blue_patch, red_patch], loc='lower left', fontsize=12)
plt.axhline(y=0.5, color='black', linestyle='--')
plt.title(r'Protein', fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel(r'# Residue', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel(r'(%)', fontsize=16)
plt.xticks(size=12)
plt.yticks(size=12)
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 10))
plt.grid()
plt.tight_layout()

# Plot
plt.subplot(423)
p = np.array(m2)
o = np.arange(len(p))
threshold = 0.5
segments_o = np.r_[o[0], o[1:-1].repeat(2), o[-1]].reshape(-1, 2)
segments_p = np.r_[p[0], p[1:-1].repeat(2), p[-1]].reshape(-1, 2)
linecolors = ['red' if p_[0] > threshold and p_[1] > threshold else 'blue'
              for p_ in segments_p]
segments = [zip(o_, p_) for o_, p_ in zip(segments_o, segments_p)]
ax = plt.axes()
ax.add_collection(LineCollection(segments, colors=linecolors))
ax.set_ylim(-0.06, 1.07)
ax.set_xlim(0,383)
blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='ordenada')
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='desordenada')
plt.legend(handles=[blue_patch, red_patch], loc='lower left', fontsize=12)
plt.axhline(y=0.5, color='black', linestyle='--')
plt.title(r'Protein', fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel(r'# Residue', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel(r'(%)', fontsize=16)
plt.xticks(size=12)
plt.yticks(size=12)
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(o), max(o)+1, 10))
plt.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

#plt.savefig('figure.png', format='png', bbox_inches="tight", dpi=300)
```

How can I solve this?
where is the problem?

Comment: Please edit your question and copy-paste the code without the ">" in front.  Use three backticks ``` before and after the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the number of plots you want to be created by [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html),

```py
nrows = 2
ncols = 2
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, sharey='row')
```

which will create an array of `axes` instances with shape `(nrows, ncols)`. You can then plot to individual `axes` via

```py
ax[0,0].plot(...)
```

Although in order to set tick properties, labels, etc for the `axes` you need to use the `axes` versions of the functions instead of the `pyplot` versions. I.e.

```py
ax[0, 0].set_xticks(...)
# instead of 
plt.xticks(...)

ax[0, 0].set_title(...)
# instead of 
plt.title(...)

ax[0, 0].set_xlabel(...)
# instead of
plt.set_xlabel(...)
```

Comment: I've tried this, but the result is the same, one big plot. I specified the rows and colums with plt.subplot(421), that's right, isnt it? Or, I don't know if I put the variables correctly,  Thanks for your answer and support.

Comment: @ThéréHernandez `plt.subplot` creates a single plot. My answer is using `plt.subplots` - which creates multiple plots. You can use `plt.subplot` but you need to call it once for each plot