# How to create one seaborn plot consisting of kx2 scatterplots with shared legend that has union of all classes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have several scatter plots, with different classes in each. I want to stick them all together in kx2 grid of plots with a legend on a side that contains all present classes, e.g remove legend from individual plots.

How do I do it?

Here is 4 plots for 2x2 test

```
from  matplotlib.lines import  Line2D
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib.lines import  Line2D

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "class":["a", "b", "e"],
    "time":[1,2,3],
    "score":[10, 20, 30]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "class":["a", "c", "d"],
    "time":[0,5,10],
    "score":[5, 25, 30]
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    "class":["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
    "time":[0,5,10,30,50],
    "score":[5, 25, 30, 40, 100]
})

df4 = pd.DataFrame({
    "class":["a", "e"],
    "time":[1,2],
    "score":[10,25]
})

def get_palette():
  pal =  {
      'a': "#4C72B0", 
      'b': "#55A868", 
      'c': "#C44E52", 
      'd': "#8172B2", 
      'e': "#CCB974", 
  }
  return pal

def get_markers():
  mark = {
      'a': Line2D.filled_markers[0], 
      'b': Line2D.filled_markers[5], 
      'c': Line2D.filled_markers[6], 
      'd': Line2D.filled_markers[7],  
      'e': Line2D.filled_markers[8], 
  }
  return mark

def get_scatterplot(source, ds_name):
  scatter = sns.scatterplot(palette=get_palette(), markers=get_markers(), 
                            edgecolor='black', alpha=0.6, x="score", y="time",
                            hue="class", style="class", s=150, 
                            data=source).set_title(ds_name)
  return scatter

scatter_df1 = get_scatterplot(df1, "df1")
plt.show()

scatter_df2 = get_scatterplot(df2, "df2")
plt.show()

scatter_df3 = get_scatterplot(df3, "df3")
plt.show()

scatter_df4 = get_scatterplot(df4, "df4")
plt.show()
```

This is what I am trying to do based on some other responses on Stack

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2)
sns.scatterplot(palette=get_palette(), markers=get_markers(), edgecolor='black', alpha=0.6, x="score", y="time", hue="class", style="class", s=150, data=df1, ax=axs[0]).set_title("ds1")
sns.scatterplot(palette=get_palette(), markers=get_markers(), edgecolor='black', alpha=0.6, x="score", y="time", hue="class", style="class", s=150, data=df2, ax=axs[1]).set_title("ds2")
sns.scatterplot(palette=get_palette(), markers=get_markers(), edgecolor='black', alpha=0.6, x="score", y="time", hue="class", style="class", s=150, data=df3, ax=axs[2]).set_title("ds3")
sns.scatterplot(palette=get_palette(), markers=get_markers(), edgecolor='black', alpha=0.6, x="score", y="time", hue="class", style="class", s=150, data=df4, ax=axs[3]).set_title("ds4")
```

But it errors, not sure why...

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'scatter'
```

Comment: You can use a custom `figlegend` to get a single legend for the entire plot, but you would have to process out the class duplicates (i.e. make an array of class names and use `np.unique`). Would that suffice for your purposes?

Comment: I am a bit confused about class duplicates... could you respond with an answer so it clarifies thing and I can accept it? I am really new to this so this hint isn't helping much :( thanks!

Comment: @WilliamMiller I have also added my attempts, but I dunno if it is near-correct or total miss

Comment: The error you’re getting in the edit is due to the way you are accessing the axes from `axs`. `fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)` returns an array of `axes` instances with shape `(nrows, ncols)` so you need to do `axs[i, j]` to retrieve a single `axes` instance (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59893148/10659910))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve your last error, you need to pass `ax` in matrix style with row/col indexing since you specify a subplot layout with `nrow` and `ncol`:

```
...

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2, figsize=(12,8))

sns.scatterplot(..., ax=axs[0,0]).set_title("ds1")
sns.scatterplot(..., ax=axs[0,1]).set_title("ds2")
sns.scatterplot(..., ax=axs[1,0]).set_title("ds3")
sns.scatterplot(..., ax=axs[1,1]).set_title("ds4")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: OP Plot]

---

To resolve your desired result for shared legend and even shared axes, consider compiling all data frames into one and run plot with `seaborn.FacetGrid`. One immediate change required is the markers function that requires a list instead of dict.
    ...

```
def get_markers_list():
  mark = [
      Line2D.filled_markers[0], 
      Line2D.filled_markers[5], 
      Line2D.filled_markers[6], 
      Line2D.filled_markers[7],  
      Line2D.filled_markers[8], 
  ]
  return mark

# COMPILE ALL DFs INTO ONE
master_df = pd.concat([df1.assign(grp="ds1"),
                       df2.assign(grp="ds2"),
                       df3.assign(grp="ds3"),
                       df4.assign(grp="ds4")])

# RUN FACET GRID
g = sns.FacetGrid(master_df, col="grp", hue="class", col_wrap=2, 
                  aspect=1.5, palette=get_palette(),
                  hue_order=list('abcde'),
                  hue_kws=dict(marker=get_markers_list()))

g = (g.map(sns.scatterplot, "score", "time", 
           edgecolor='black', alpha=0.6, s=150)
      .add_legend())

plt.show()
```

[image: Proposed Plot]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`matplotlib.pyplot.figlegend`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figlegend.html) to make a single legend for the figure. Without passing any arguments this will create a legend from the "*existing artists on every axis.*" If you want to customize this you can provide the legend handles and labels directly.

Since you are specifying the colors for each 'class' explicitly it is quite easy to compose a custom legend:

```py
pal = get_palette()
handles = [Line2D([0], [0], color=c) for l, c in pal.items()]
labels = [l for l in pal]
plt.figlegend(handles=handles, labels=labels, loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Should do the trick. With `plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)` and the question code this would give you a legend that looks like this

[image]

Note that this will work for any number of classes and any number of subplots in any configuration provided the classes and their corresponding colors are all defined in `pal`, else a more advanced method would need to be employed.